# How to migrate SharePoint 2007 Shared Services User Profiles to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, migration, user-profile-service

How can I migrate the User Profiles in SharePoint 2007 (including custom fields) to the SharePoint 2010 User Profile Service?

I'm finding it difficult to find clear steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you should follow

1. Take a backup of the MOSS 2007 SSP and the My Site databases through SQL Server.
2. Restore the SSP database as `Profile DB` and the My Site Content database as `WSS_Content_MySites` in the SharePoint 2010 -SQL Server instance.
3. Create a Web Application through SharePoint 2010 Central Administration to host My Site.
4. Attach and upgrade the restored 2007 My Sites database (i.e. WSS_Content_MySites) using the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.
5. Turn off the following services in your SharePoint 2010 Central Administration site:

   - User Profile Service
   - User Profile Synchronization Service.
6. Now delete the existing User Profile Service Application(s) if they already exist [ in Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications]

   - Make sure to check the box to delete the associated data/content
   - Reset IIS
7. Create a new User Profile Service Application in Central Administration [Central Administration –> Manage Service Applications –> New]

   - Name = User Profile Service Application.
   - Create New App Pool.
   - Use the restored 2007 SSP database as the “Profile Database Name” (Profile_DB).
   - Accept all other default database names.
   - Enter the newly created MySites web application URL (e.g. `http://mysites`) as the default MySites location for the new User Profile Service Application.
   - Go to “Administrators” in the ribbon menu for the User Profile Service Application and verify that DOMAIN\farm_account has “Full Control” rights.
   - Start the User Profile Service in Central Administration [Central Administration –> Application Management –> Manage Services on Server].
8. Start the User Profile Synchronization service in Central Administration [Central Administration –> Application Management –> Manage Services on Server]

   - Use the DOMAIN\farm_account credentials.
   - This will take a few minutes…
   - Follow progress in the ULSViewer.exe if you are concerned it is failing & filter by Category=”User Profile”.
   - Reset IIS.
9. In services.msc on your Central Administration host server (i.e. “App Server”), verify the two ForeFront Identity Management Windows services.

   - Services are started.
   - Set to startup type “Automatic”.
   - Running as DOMAIN\farm_account.
10. Setup the Profile Import [Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application - click on title]
11. Click on the link to “Add New Synchronization Connection”

    - Name = DOMAIN
    - Forest Name = sub.domain.local
    - Specify a DC = dc.sub.domain.local
    - Authentication = Windows Authentication
    - Account Name = DOMAIN\ad_sync_account
    - Make sure your chosen account has “Replicating Changes” rights in AD.
    - Click “Populate Containers”.
    - Click “Select All” and click the 'OK' Button.
12. Run a Full Import

    - Central Administration –> Manage Service Applications” -> “User Profile Service Application” -> “Start Profile Synchronization” -> select the Full Import radio button option
    - This will take a few minutes.
13. Setup Profile Sync schedules [Central Administration –> Monitoring –> Timer Jobs]
14. Now we have done everything and it’s time now to test the MySites site with a domain user account.

Source - http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1110

Comment: Thank you Amal. Will this also copy the custom properties? How can I determine in what database these custom properties are stored?

Comment: The Service Application database has all those information. You need to take care of only two databases, the SSP and mysites.

Comment: Do you mean the Service Application database in SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Okay thanks Amal. So by migrating a copy of the Profile DB and the Mysite DB, i will have migrated the custom user profile fields as well?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer, but i have not yet tested it. Hope you're right :)

Comment: Migration should be planned properly. Also make sure you do it in TEST environments first, and then do it in actual production. Best of luck!